# Is there is a better approach to do a task after x seconds?

Tags: c++

I want to do execute this function after x seconds.
this is my pseudo code.

```
object x;
std::thread([&]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        //execute some code
        x.removeEffect();
        }).detach();
```

Is there is better way to do this, since create new thread is expensive.

UPDATE**
sorry for miss explain.
I also want to execute the code below this thread creation as well.
so the full code would be.

```
void handleThis(object x)
{
std::thread([&]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        //execute some code
        x.removeEffect();
        }).detach();
//execute some code too
x.startEffect();
}
```

UPDATE**
make pseudo code more clearly

```
void handleThis(object x)
{
std::thread([&]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        //execute some code
        x.functionAA();
        }).detach();
//execute some code too
x.functionBB();
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous. If `x` goes out of scope, which is captured by reference in the lambda, you will have a dangling refgerence -> UB. What is it what you want to achieve? Could be a [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: C++20 coroutines would be a good fit for this task. Not sure how good library support is atm tho.

Comment: You should `startEffect()` before you start the thread that does `removeEffect()`, because if you do it as shown, there is a miniscule chance that the thread gets to do `removeEffect()` before `startEffect()` is reached. That's not a big deal in practice if the delay is 5 seconds, but will become important if the timings are tighter.

Comment: If coroutines are not an options, you could implement a *thread pool*. A pool would create some threads at the beginning and reuse them for every task that is needed. But it would be an overkill if this is the only task that you need to execute in parallel.

Comment: @user1810087 Yes, It true that pass by reference might cause an another issue if 'x' is not there after x second. I might consider to by pass pointer instead and check if object is nullptr before execute any code.

Comment: @j6t Thank you for point me this problem. The acutally code that I want to do it not something like startEffect() and removeEffect() sorry for unclear method name. I'm going to update in order to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a thread-pool and push a functor as a task for this thread-pool.
This will solve 2 your problems:

1. Don't need to create a new thread for each execution.
2. Your Task can receive delay as an argument and thread-pool will execute task with required delay.